# String small replacement

Tags: c#, string

I am searching for a simple way to remove underscores from strings and replacing the next character with its upper case letter.

For example:

```
From: "data" to: "Data"
From: "data_first" to: "DataFirst"
From: "data_first_second" to: "DataFirstSecond"
```

Comment: This seems  like a pretty good fit for regex...

Comment: Regex solution is best for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who needs more than one line of code?

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?:^|_)($|.)", m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach is known as a "finite-state machine" that iterates through the string - in that it has a finite set of states ("is the first letter of a word following an underscore" vs "character inside a word"). This represents the minimal instructions needed to perform the task. You can use a Regular Expression for the same effect, but it would generate at least the same number of instructions at runtime. Writing the code out manually guarantees a minimal runtime.

The advantage of this approach is sheer performance: there is no unnecessary allocation of intermediate strings being performed, and it iterates through the input string only once, giving a time complexity of O(n) and a space complexity of O(n). This cannot be improved upon.

```
public static String ConvertUnderscoreSeparatedStringToPascalCase(String input) {

    Boolean isFirstLetter = true;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder( input.Length );
    foreach(Char c in input) {

        if( c == '_' ) {
            isFirstLetter = true;
            continue;
        }

        if( isFirstLetter ) {

            output.Append( Char.ToUpper( c ) );
            isFirstLetter = false;
        }
        else {
            output.Append( c );
        }
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Passing `capacity` to `StringBuilder` constructor with the length of `input` can improve performance

Comment: +1 [JsFiddle Proof](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rqXYmN). (Although I'm not a fan of low-quality questions that show no effort on the posters behalf)

Comment: @haim770 thanks - I've added that optimization.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I know, I'm just bored

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
string test = "data_first_second";

string[] testArray=test.Split('_');

StringBuilder modifiedString = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string t in testArray)
{
     modifiedString.Append(t.First().ToString().ToUpper() + t.Substring(1));
}
test=modifiedString.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split` and following LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<string> newStrings = "data_first_second".Split('_')
   .Select(t => new String(t.Select((c, index) => index == 0 ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToArray()));
string result = String.Join("", newStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers valid... for a culture-aware way:

```
var textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
var modifiedString = textInfo.ToTitleCase(originalString).Replace("_","")
```

I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAr5PP

Comment: `ToTitleCase` is NOT culture-aware in .NET, it always blindly converts the first character to uppercase, including (in `en-US`) words like "the", "and" and "of".

Comment: That would also convert characters after spaces to upper case and uppercase letters that are not after underscores to lower case

Comment: @Dai Why would this be a bad thing in this context?

Comment: @Dai it's culture-aware in nature (maybe not in implementation) :-)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I'd say that was the op's intent, but I might be wrong... it definitely works with his examples, but yeah, it's not all specced :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ and [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
var result = string.Join("",str.Split('_')
             .Select(c => c.First().ToString()
             .ToUpper() + String.Join("", c.Skip(1))));
```